# How to bookmark a favorite without loading the page first? (Internet Explorer, Firefox)

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, browser, internet-explorer

I need to add a bookmark to IE but when I go to the site, it redirects to another page. I don't want to bookmark that page. I want to bookmark the original page before it redirects. How do I do this in Internet Explorer and Firefox?

(To do this in Chrome, open Bookmark Manager (Crtl + Shift + O) and click Organize > Add page.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Firefox, open your Bookmarks library Ctrl+Shift+B, and then just right click, "New Bookmark", and you can add the bookmark details without browsing to it.

Answer (score 1):

Go to:

```
C:\Users\YourUser\Favorites\
```

Then just add in a shortcut to the webpage. All done!

Comment: You can also bookmark any page in IE or Firefox then change the url after the fact.  An answer like this, isn't something I normally would consider an answer, but sometimes simple questions have simple solutions though.

Answer (score 0):

Press CTRL + D (regardless of which site you're in, even about:blank)
Give a title/name and press ENTER

Press CTRL + B, right-click the shortcut you created, click Properties, change the URL and click OK.